# How can I find CSS files Recursively?

Tags: php, html, css

Is there a way for me to search for css files recursively using the following code?

The directory I'm searching is "themes/Evolution". I want it to search for css files in the sub-directories as well.

```html
<?php
 
// Does not support flag GLOB_BRACE
function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags); 
    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
        $files = array_merge($files, rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    }
    return $files;
}
 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$directoryWhereToSearch = 'themes/Evolution';
$allFiles = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directoryWhereToSearch));
$cssFiles = new RegexIterator($allFiles, '/\.css$/i');
foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
    echo $cssFile->getFilename();
}
```

Comment: Do I just add the dir "themes/Evolution" to getRealPath?

Comment: This works but is there a way to not see the entire directory name? I only want the filename.

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks a bunch Kazz! You were a big help!